# Convert binary to hex in node.js

Tags: node.js

I want to ask I want to convert my binary data to hex before I will insert this to my table.

```
var net  = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function(socket){

    socket.on('data',function(data){
    var bindata= data.toString('binary');

    //filter(bindata);

    //if no error convert to hex.
    var hexdata = bindata.toString('hex');

    //insert hexdata here.
});

server.listen(3030,'127.0.0.1', function () {
    console.log("server is listenining");
});
```

but the problem is that the binary data will be inserted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
parseInt("10101001", 2).toString(16)
// => "a9"
```

EDIT: I think I misunderstood the question. Your `data` starts out as `Buffer`, then you convert it to a string, then you want it as hex? If so, just do `data.toString('hex')`. If you have already manipulated `bindata`, then reconstruct into a buffer:

```
var bindata = data.toString('binary');
// do something with bindata
var hexdata = new Buffer(bindata, 'ascii').toString('hex');
```

Comment: Why ascii? Because that is what you would get in your original `data` buffer if someone was sending `application/x-octet-stream`-compatible content. If they were sending UTC strings, then I assume you wouldn't be messing with hex in the first place.

Comment: can I ask why is it after I converted into image file,the image is not properly converted enventhough I get the complete binary image data.there is stripe lines along the image.

Comment: With no access to your code or your image file, no idea. `diff` it. Use vbindiff or bsdiff or similar to find what is actually different.

Comment: I already ask here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30272013/node-js-not-properly-converting-binary-image-back-to-image-file , but no one tries to attempt to help me. I hope you can help me.Thank you in advance.

Comment: I will try to put in pastie all the binary image data that was save in my db.I'll be back

Comment: Pasties are not for binary files... I can't see anything that way. Use the tools I recommended, see what is actually different. Also I noticed that in the linked questions you didn't use `binary`/`ascii`, so you're leaving it to defaults and chance?

Comment: I tried to extract the table with binary file but after extracting the data is changing to other format I don't why...yes I did not use binary/ascii ,but I think I already tried use binary /ascii but stil the image is having stripe lines...Okay I will try the tools you recommend.

Comment: It is difficult to use the tool bsdiff.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
parseInt("1111", 2).toString(16);
```

Second param in parseInt is radix its represent "111" value to binary and toString(16) convert it to hex.

Comment: This appears to be the same as the [existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30183127/1072229).